# how to pass a closure as a parameter in method channel's invokeMethod in Flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, function, closures, flutter-plugin

In my native implementation, I have a method that takes two string parameters and a closure. It is a login function. So what it does is to use the user's id and password to decide if the user is allowed to log in. The closure takes a boolean parameter that means the login is either success or failure. Based on the boolean, the contents of the closure takes corresponding actions. In order to make this method available to plugin users, I created this in the dart part:

```
Future<void>login(String username, String password, void Function(bool isSuccess) callback) async {
   return await methodChannel.invokeMethod('login', 
         {'username': username, 'password': password, 'callback': callback}
   );
}
```

But the above code caused an error: Exception has occurred. ArgumentError (Invalid argument: Closure: (bool) => void).

It didn't even reach the native code. This looks like that passing closure or function is not allowed?

Comment: and why don't you use it as `Future<bool>login(String username, String password)`?

Comment: @pskink I have to pass a closure to the native implementation. What you proposed didn't achieve this. Also, changing the native implementation is not possible. It is a compiled library that is included in the plugin.

Comment: so your compiled plugin documentation is wrong as you cannot pass any callbacks to `MethodChannel`, for more read this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/StandardMessageCodec-class.html

Comment: The native code had been around for a long time. The initial intention was to support only native Android and iOS apps. Now that Flutter's popularity increases, and there is a need to support Flutter, it seems necessary to update the native code to have some methods that do not use callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, functions are not supported. See [Platform channel data types support](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#codec) for details.

Comment: This is too bad. So it means that this native functionality cannot be exposed to plugin users? Do you think there is an alternative way?

Comment: It can be, but not in the format of function callback. You can always return the result of login instead of using callback.

Comment: It looks like the original native code needs to be updated to allow it to return a boolean.